# TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on 'string | SelectValue'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get value from the object, however, TypeScript doesn't understand what I am doing.
Here's a piece of code:

```
interface SelectValue {
  label: string;
  value: number;
}

interface FormValues {
  entity: SelectValue | string;
}

const makeFullDataObject = (formValues: FormValues) => ({
  entity: formValues.entity.value || formValues.entity,
});
```

Error says:

```
TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string | SelectValue'.   Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I do know that this property does not exist on string type, that is why I  put OR string. This works just fine in JavaScript, but TypeScript won't let me compile this. Any solutions without using `any`? Thanks

Comment: `string` type does not contain a `value` property, only `SelectValue` does, that is why you get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not giving TypeScript enough information. As far as it is concerned, `formValues.entity` can be a string and therefore not have a `value` property. You should try to narrow down its type. Here's an example:

```js
function isSelectValue(entity: string | SelectValue): entity is SelectValue {
  return typeof (entity as any).value === 'string';
}
```

Then later:

```js
const makeFullDataObject = (formValues: FormValues) => ({
  entity: isSelectValue(formValues.entity) ? formValues.entity.value : formValues.entity,
});
```

Comment: Well, okay then. I really hoped I could avoid this manual type checking and let TS figure it out.